# Why isn't reloadData() working?

Tags: swift, collections, view, uicollectionview

I'm using the UICollectionView in two different apps. One the UICollectionView is contained, the other not. 
I am able to use reloadData() to refresh the CollectionView when the view appears however in the app with code below, it insists I use self.collectionView!.reloadData() with a ! or ? as "UICollectionView not unwrapped" and then it doesn't reload the collectionView when the view re-appears, only works then I totally quite and relaunch the app.

```
    class SecondViewController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

var imageArray = [UIImage]()
var assetCollection: PHAssetCollection = PHAssetCollection()
let albumName = "Euphoria"
var albumFound : Bool = false
var photosAsset: PHFetchResult<PHAsset>!






override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)

    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
    if let _:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{

        //found the album
        self.albumFound = true
        self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject! as PHAssetCollection

    }else{
        var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
        //create the folder
        NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollection(withTitle: self.albumName)
            albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
        },
                                               completionHandler: {(success, error)in
                                                if(success){
                                                    print("Successfully created folder")
                                                    self.albumFound = true
                                                    let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(withLocalIdentifiers: [albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil)
                                                    self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject! as PHAssetCollection
                                                }else{
                                                    print("Error creating folder")
                                                    self.albumFound = false
                                                }
        })
    }



    grabPhotos()






}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    self.collectionView!.reloadData()
}




func grabPhotos(){

    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]


    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options:nil){

        if fetchResult.count > 0 {

            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{

                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width:200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {

                    image, error in

                    self.imageArray.append(image!)

                })
            }

        }
        else{
            print("you got no photos!")


        }


    }
}









override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return imageArray.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

    let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UIImageView

    imageView.image = imageArray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `collectionView!.reloadData()` has been called (in `viewWillAppear`) before `grabPhotos()` finishes it job.

I suggest to debug the sorting of executing the code, by adding two *breakpoints*, one at the `self.collectionView!.reloadData()` line and the other one at `self.imageArray.append(image!)` line to check which one has been reached first.

Instead of adding `self.collectionView!.reloadData()` in `viewWillAppear`, you might want to add it in `grabPhotos()` method after finishing appending to  `imageArray`, as follows:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // remove it from here
}

func grabPhotos() {
    let imgManager = PHImageManager.default()

    let requestOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
    requestOptions.isSynchronous = true
    requestOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat

    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: false)]

    if let fetchResult : PHFetchResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: self.assetCollection, options:nil){
        if fetchResult.count > 0 {
            for i in 0..<fetchResult.count{
                imgManager.requestImage(for: fetchResult.object(at: i) as PHAsset, targetSize: CGSize(width:200, height: 200), contentMode: .aspectFill, options: requestOptions, resultHandler: {
                    image, error in
                    self.imageArray.append(image!)
                })
            }

            // there we go...
            self.collectionView!.reloadData()

        } else{
            print("you got no photos!")
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the data you use to fill your collection view is created in the ViewDidLoad method. This method only gets called once the first time this View Controller is presented unlike the ViewWillAppear method which is called every single time the View Controller is presented. So even though the collectionView does attempt to reload the data every time the view controller is presented, the data never changes. In order to get new data, you need to move the code (the grabPhotos method) that refreshes the data to the ViewWillAppear method.

Comment: I've tried adding the grabPhotos() method into the ViewWillAppear however then it grabs the photos every-time the view appears and duplicates them. So say there are 10 photos in the album, every time the view appears it doubles.

Comment: Instead of appending those elements to the imageArray you should reset the imageArray to equal the new results.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, I'm a complete beginner but will try look into what you've said and figure something out. Not totally sure how to go about implementing what you're suggesting

Comment: Run this line of code every time before the grabPhotos method is called: 

self.imageArray.removaAllObjects()

This will empty the array so that it does not duplicate data.